# How can I encode and decode the depth image with opencv? I use the following code to get a depth image in webots, but fail. Thanks a lot

Tags: c++, opencv, webots

```
    // `s` is the webots's rangefinder
    auto buffer = (float*)s->getRangeImage();
    cv::Mat img(cv::Size(width, height), CV_32FC1, buffer);  // image data is float*

    // check and success.
    // imshow("pic", img); 
    // cvWaitKey(0);

    // encode:
    std::vector<uchar> newBuffer;
    cv::imencode(".jpg", img, newBuffer);

    // decode
    auto img_decode = cv::imdecode(newBuffer, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    // fail and get a black image
    imshow("pic", img_decode);
    cvWaitKey(0);
```

I have try to use other params in function `cv::imdecode` like `cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH` but fail. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Not sure, but encoding to jpg might require a uint8 (8U) image, not float (32F). And usually it's 3 channels.

Comment: imencode might just convert floats to uint8, same as imwrite does. these two are supposed to be **identical** except for where the data ends up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is real, i.e. floating point, and single channel, you could try writing to a PFM or TIFF format image which will support that data type.

As @wohlstad mentions in the comments, JPEG is uint8 so only supports integers in the range 0..255.

Comment: It works when I use  `cv::imencode(".tif", img, newBuffer);`. Thanks a lot.